# Target leak in Customer Churn Model

Tags: input, statistics, prediction, feature-selection, data-science-experience

I am working on a customer churn model and I have a few doubts to confirm if there is a target leak or not due to certain features. Please, find the details below:

Customer base: Live as of Dec'22
Response (Target) definition: Customers dropping their bank balances by 60% or more in the quarter: Feb Mar Apr (FMA'23) as compared to the previous year same quarter: Feb Mar Apr (FMA'22)

For example; If a customer's AQB (average quarterly balance) in Feb Mar Apr (FMA'22) was Rs. 1,00,000, which dropped to Rs. 40,000 in Feb Mar Apr (FMA'23), then the customer will be our target (Target = 1)

Problem Statement:

While fitting a model for prediction, should I use AQB of FMA'22 as a feature or will that cause target leak (since, it is being used in the calculation of target).

I fitted a model in both situations:

1. Using FMA'22 AQB (Recall: 90%)
2. Not using FMA'22 AQB (Recall: 78%)

There is a major drop of 12% in the model performance if I am not using the PRE-AQB (FMA'22) in the input features.

Request your help to understand if this is a case of target leak or not?

I fitted a model in both situations:

1. Using FMA'22 AQB (Recall: 90%)
2. Not using FMA'22 AQB (Recall: 78%)

There is a major drop of 12% in the model performance if I am not using the PRE-AQB (FMA'22) in the input features.

Request your help to understand if this is a case of target leak or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried computing the heat map for feature correlations using chi -squared and then with cramer's V. Please go through it and try training after dropping some of the highly correlated features (>.30).